# Direct product of groups of homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, direct-product

This is really a notational thing that is kind of irking me. Consider the dual group of $G=Z_n\times Z_m$, so $G$ is a finite abelian group. I can get an order $n$ homomorphism $\varphi_n$ from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$. I can also get an order $m$ homomorphism $\varphi_m$ from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$.

We can then consider the direct product $\langle \varphi_n\rangle\times\langle\varphi_m\rangle$. This is clearly a group. Yet I am a little confused by what the elements of this group are. Is the element $(\varphi_n,\varphi_m)\in \langle \varphi_n\rangle\times\langle\varphi_m\rangle$ still a homomorphism?

My question is based off of this question: [Help with proof for problem 14 chapter 5 Dummit and Foote.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017987/help-with-proof-for-problem-14-chapter-5-dummit-and-foote)
and how they were able to say that $\langle \chi_1\rangle\times\cdots\times\langle\chi_r\rangle\leq \hat{G}$. It is not clear to me how we can interpret elements of the direct product as homomorphisms. Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are really dealing with a *biproduct*: the product here is playing the role of the co-product, not of the product. If $P$ is the product of $A$ and $B$, and $C$ is an object and we have maps $f\colon C\to A$ and $g\colon C\to B$, then the universal property of the product induces a unique morphism $C\to P$ which is often denoted $f\times g$ (and better, written as $f\times g\colon C\to A\times B$). Similarly, given $j\colon A\to D$ and $k\colon B\to D$, there is a unique map $A\amalg B\to D$ which is often denoted $j\amalg k$. (cont)

Comment: What you have here is that $G$ is both the product and the coproduct of $Z_n$ and $Z_m$ in the category of abelian groups. So your pair of maps induces a unique map from $Z_n\times Z_m$ in its guise as a coproduct. The “element” $(\varphi_n,\varphi_m)$ is really the map induced by the pair of maps and the universal property, though it is defined “coordinatewise”, as $(\varphi_n,\varphi_m)(a,b) = \varphi_n(a)\varphi_m(b)$ (using multiplicative notation), which works because everything is abelian.